# Rendered template is not loading relevant model

Tags: ember.js

Relevant information

- I have a Rails 4.0 API server set up for data persistence, using ember-rails.
- Ember Version: 1.3.0-beta.1+canary
- Ember-Data Version: 1.0.0-beta.4+canary

Say I have a Categories model that contains a list of categories. I would like to render this at the Application level to be used as navigation.

Here is what I have

```
# templates/application.hbs
{{ render categories }}
{{ outlet }}

# templates/categories.hbs
<h1>Categories</h1>
{{#each category in controller}}
    {{#link-to 'category' category}}
        {{category.title}}
    {{/link-to}}
{{/each}}

# routes/categories.js.coffee
App.CategoriesRoute = Ember.Route.extend
    model: ->
        @store.find 'category'

# models/category.js.coffee
App.Category = DS.Model.extend
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    slug: DS.attr('string')

# router.js.coffee
App.Router.map ->
    @resource 'categories', path: 'categories'
    @resource 'category', path: 'category/:slug'
```

Accessing the /#/categories path renders what I expect; a double of headings and the list of links, each pointing to a category.

If I access the root of the app (Application.Index) at '/', I am expecting to see the same result, albeit only a single rendering of a list of links. However, what results is just the single heading and no links. Using the Ember Inspector, it looks like there isn't a model tied to the {{ render categories }}.

From my understanding, rendering a template will use the relevant controller and view. What would be the correct way to bind the relevant model to the rendered template? Or better yet, what would be the best practice to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `{{render categories}}`, it will render the categories template with the categories controller. The CategoriesRoute  is only used when going to the categories route in the url.  In order to have the categories information available at the application level you will need to fetch the categories at that level and store it on the application controller somewhere for use when you render.

```
 // controller would be application controller, and technically you wouldn't need to write controller
 {{ render 'categories' controller.categories }}
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/IleQEFa/1/edit

In the example I'm attaching an additional set of models under the name someitems on the application controller.  I'm doing this during the setupController, this is the hook that's fired after the model has been resolved in that route.

For you, in the setupController I'd do something like

```
 this.store.find('category').then( function(records){ controller.set('categories', records)});
```

or maybe this, I'm not familiar with coffeescript

```
 @store.find("category").then (records) ->
   controller.set "categories", records
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Adding the controller.categories option didn't load the data. I've also tried adding need: ['categories'] under the ApplicationController, which under inspector showed a model=<App.CategoriesController:ember310> binding to the render, but looking under the Data section shows 0 records for App.Category

Comment: Sorry, you misunderstood me, you need to fetch the categories in the application route, and attach them to your application controller under the name categories (or any name for that matter).  There isn't any real ember hookup magic going on here, you need to manually get the data and hook it up

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Been trying to wrap my ahead around Ember. I was able to pull the data and attached it the controller. However, the template isn't rendering the data. Moving the contents of the categories template to the application template itself and iterating controller.categories worked. I'm guessing that I'm not referencing the passed model correctly in the categories template?

Comment: I was able to use partial to render the categories.hbs template with the data successfully by swapping out controller with controller.categories in the each helper. I'm guessing I am able to do this since partials inherit the controller of the parent?

Comment: Nevermind. I was able to figure it out by rereading your jsbin with a clear head. When passing in the model through render at the application render, I had to remove the controller. prefix. Thank you for your patience!

Comment: Hah, I totally understand that.  Next morning me is always better than night time me, 10 minutes to fix an issue versus 4 hours late at night.